# Using Axios to return stream from Express app -- "The provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType."

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm learning Node, Express and React and am trying to convert a simple generic Fetch method that I use to call my Express API to Axios.  I've gotten Axios to work when I want it to automatically return the result as JSON data, but here I want it to return a `ReadableStream`.  From the documentation it should be simple: simply add the field `responseType:'stream'` to the `config` but I keep getting the error `The provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.`   I see that others have had this issue (see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1474)but I don't see any solution.  Does anyone know if there is one, or if I am doing something wrong?  The relevant code is below.  Thanks for any insights!

```
const logic = {

 _call(path, method, headers, body, expectedStatus) {
        const config = { method,responseType:'stream', url: `http://localhost:8080/${path}`}

        if (headers) config.headers = headers
        if (body) config.data = body

        return axios( config)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === expectedStatus) {
                    return res
                } else
                    return res
                        .then(({ message }) => {
                            throw new Error(message)
                        })
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[This answer might be worth checking out if you explicitly need the stream in Axios.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71534399/10543130)

That said, I prefer the default `fetch` for more flexibility. If anyone is interested, here's a client side approach to get a stream as a list of iterable chunks.

From top to bottom, here's how the final call looks like:

```js
const stream = await generateStream()
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  console.log(chunk)
}
```

The `generateStream` function is the one doing the actual API call, it looks like this:

```js
export const generateStream = async (): Promise<AsyncIterable<string>> => {
  const response = await fetch(
    'http://localhost:5000/api/stream/dummy?chunks_amount=50',
    {
      method: 'GET',
    }
  )
  if (response.status !== 200) throw new Error(response.status.toString())
  if (!response.body) throw new Error('Response body does not exist')
  return getIterableStream(response.body)
}
```

And finally, here's the `getIterableStream` function that reads the byte chunks as they are loaded and decodes them to a string:

```js
export async function* getIterableStream(
  body: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>
): AsyncIterable<string> {
  const reader = body.getReader()
  const decoder = new TextDecoder()

  while (true) {
    const { value, done } = await reader.read()
    if (done) {
      break
    }
    const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true })
    yield decodedChunk
  }
}
```

Please note the star in `async function* getIterableStream`. This syntax defines an [asynchronous generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator) function.

Comment: Bless you for that working code. I tried all day trying to make streaming responses work and could wrap my head around it!