# HTTP Stream using Axios (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I'm trying to stream price data via HTTP (Don't know why they don't use websockets..) and I use axios to make normal REST API requests but I don't know how to handle 'Transfer Encoding': 'chunked' type of requests.

This code just hangs and doesn't produce any error so assume it's working but not able to process the response:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`https://stream.example.com`, {headers: 
{Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet- 
stream'}})

console.log(data) // execution hangs before reaching here
```

Appreciate your help.

WORKING SOLUTION:
As pointed out from the answer below, we need to add a responseType: stream as an axios option and also add an event listener on the response.

Working code:

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://stream.example.com`, {
  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}, 
  responseType: 'stream'
});

const stream = response.data
stream.on('data', data => { 
  data = data.toString()
  console.log(data) 
})
```

Comment: HTTP streams are far simpler than websockets, and can take advantage of HTTP/2

Answer (score 33, accepted):

FYI, sending the `content-type` header for a GET request is meaningless.  The content-type header applies to the BODY of the http request and there is no body for a GET request.

With the `axios()` library, if you want to get direct access to the response stream, you use the `responseType` option to tell Axios that you want access to the raw response stream:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://stream.example.com', {
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
    responseType: 'stream'
});

const stream = response.data;

stream.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data);
});

stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log("stream done");
});
```

Axios document reference [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now able to print the response, which has a 200 HTTP Code, and the stream is kept alive. How do I process new data as it comes in? Is there some event handler like stream.on('message', function() { //do something} ) ? I can't find it in the docs

Comment: It is presumably an [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) object which is a sub-class of the standard nodejs [stream.readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable-streams).  You would use `stream.on('data', data => { console.log(data) });` to get notified of incoming data on the stream.  The data arrives in arbitrary chunks (perhaps even split among different `data` events so you will have to know what the format is and parse it appropriately.

Comment: That worked! Adding the event listener on stream as you described did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @jfriend00 `stream.on` exactly what I needed. I can't find any reference to this though in the docs. Is it that I missed it or are they yet to document this? Where can I find a list of other events apart from `on` that I can listen to?

Comment: @ericgithinji - Axios, when run in nodejs, is returning a nodejs [readStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) so you use the nodejs doc for that.

Comment: It does NOT work, it gives "xhr.js:211 The provided value 'stream' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType."

Comment: @CRSardar - Please post your own question and show your own code.  This concept works and worked for the question here. Your situation is apparently different so we would need to see your exact code in order to help you.  Your particular error sounds like you are using TypeScript and/or sounds like perhaps you are not using axios or not using the right TypeScript typedefs for axios. But, let's not fix or debate that here.  Please post your own question and show your own code. Also a downvote here is perhaps not really useful to anyone. Your situation is different and needs its own question.

Comment: I'm still looking for proper documentation on this. The `data.on` solution is still documented exactly nowhere... but at least it works...

Comment: @BennyBottema - Yeah, it's not really documented very well.  But, when using Axios within nodejs, it puts a regular readstream object in `response.data` and that's a full-on nodejs readstream and all the methods and features that belong to a nodejs readstream are available on it.  Yes, they don't redocument all the features of a readstream because they don't need to.  It would be nice if they said `response.data` was a regular nodejs readstream in the doc, but that's what it is.  `response.data.on('data', ...)` is just regular readstream logic.  You can also pipe it or read from it directly.

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems getting it to work with axios ([mainly this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1474)). Therefore I ended up using the fetch API, allowing me do this elegantly in client side code:

```js
const stream = await generateStream()
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  console.log(chunk)
}
```

Here's [the full answer that uses the fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77107457/10543130) from another similar thread. It includes the a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Since NodeJS 10 you can also use asynchronous iteration to read from streams. Read more [here](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_async-iteration.html#async-iteration-over-node.js-streams).

```
const response = await axios.get('https://stream.example.com', {
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
    responseType: 'stream'
});

const stream = response.data;

for await (const chunk of stream) {
    console.log(chunk);
}
```