# How to receive data as chunks when we have large response data using axios module in nodejs. Something alternative of res.on of https module

Tags: node.js, rest, https, axios, buffer

```
let req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        chunks.push(d);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse((Buffer.concat(chunks)).toString()));
    });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

The above code is done using https module.
The response is very big so I am receiving it as chunks.
I want same thing (receiving data as chunks) using axios module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Stream using Axios (Node JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534322/http-stream-using-axios-node-js)

Comment: @Matt -> For me I am getting an error. stream.on('data', d => {
    TypeError: stream.on is not a function

Comment: async function A() {
    let chunks = [];
    const response = await axios.get('https://mocki.io/v1/3449b0c8-4fad-4a03-ba12-507113e15464', {
        headers: {//Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
            responseType: 'stream'
        }
    });
    const stream = response.data
    stream.on('data', d => {
        console.log("@1@chunks");
        chunks.push(d);
        //console.log(data);
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log("stream done");
    });
}
A();